# Different responses depending on request tool

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, retrofit, okhttp

I've created a rest-framework view to create an object.

Unfortunately, I get different responses if:

- I use the browsableAPI interface with raw data : 201 CREATED
- I use Hurl.it, (see parameters) : 201 CREATED
- I use curl (`curl -d @sample.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin -i "https://vincentle.pythonanywhere.com/samples/api/create/"`) : 302 FOUND
- I use OkHttp/Retrofit in an Android app : 302 FOUND

Can you help me, at least in providing some debug strategies?

views:

```
class SampleCreateAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        room = serializer.validated_data['room']
        building = room.area.floor.building
        admins = building.customer_account.admin.all()
        if self.request.user in admins:
            super(SampleCreateAPIView, self).perform_create(serializer)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied(detail=_('You are not in the administrators list for this room'))
```

serializers:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, queryset=Room.objects.all())
    wifiaccesspoint_set = WifiAccessPointSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = ('room', 'wifiaccesspoint_set',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        wap_data = validated_data.pop('wifiaccesspoint_set')
        sample = Sample(room=validated_data['room'])
        sample.save()
        for wap in wap_data:
            WifiAccessPoint.objects.create(sample=sample, **wap)
        return sample
```

**Edit 1 - Seems a curl problem**
This command: `curl -u admin -i "https://vincentle.pythonanywhere.com/fr/samples/api/create/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @sample.json` is working fine and I get a 201 CREATED response.

But this command: `curl -d @sample.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u admin -i "https://vincentle.pythonanywhere.com/samples/api/create/"` is giving me a 302 FOUND response.

What is the difference between those 2 commands?

Comment: You can compare the request header of curl and browsable API for starters. You are already using `-i` in your curl request, now all you need to do is to see network tab of your browser's developer options. It would be best if you could share the headers.

Comment: See edit for precisions

Comment: Can you share the curl output? If character/space limitation is the issue then you can use some online application like [dpaste](http://dpaste.de) to post curl output information?

Answer (score 0):

302 is a redirection. Since you're using authentication, double check where the redirection goes.

If it's to a login page, my feeling is you're not authenticated because you don't have the right auth scheme configured. `curl -u` will probably send basic auth which you need to setup on your API (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication)

Comment: Redirection is the good path to debug. In fact my two curl commands are requesting different ressources: /samples/api/create and /fr/samples/api/create ! I will check my api url config..

Comment: If it prepends language information, your API is likely behind a i18n_pattern. Removing it should solve the redirection issue.

Comment: yes, I've done that, making it only available at /api/something